# Does the SQL Spec require a GROUP BY in EXISTS ()

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, group-by, sql-standard, exists

Microsoft currently permits this syntax.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS g(x)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM ( VALUES (1),(1) )
    AS t(x)
  WHERE g.x = t.x
  HAVING count(*) > 1
);
```

Notice that there is no `GROUP BY` in the `EXISTS` clause, is that valid ANSI SQL. Or is it merely exposing an implementation detail.

For reference, this same syntax isn't permitted in PostgreSQL.

> ERROR:  column "t.x" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

But this syntax is permitted..

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS g(x)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1  -- This changed from the first query
  FROM ( VALUES (1),(1) )
    AS t(x)
  WHERE g.x = t.x
  HAVING count(*) > 1
);
```

And this syntax is permitted.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS g(x)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM ( VALUES (1),(1) )
    AS t(x)
  WHERE g.x = t.x
  GROUP BY t.x  -- This changed from the first query
  HAVING count(*) > 1
);
```

*Question arises from [a conversation with @ErikE in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36248315#36248315)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found it in the SQL 2011 spec...

> If the `<select list>` “*” is simply contained in a `<table subquery>` that is immediately contained in an `<exists predicate>`, then the `<select list>` is equivalent to a `<value expression>` that is an arbitrary `<literal>`.

This confirms that by `*` not being equivalent to an arbitrary literal in this context that **it is in fact PostgreSQL breaking the spec.**

Keep in mind this is a distinct problem from

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (1),(2),(3) ) AS t(x)
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Which both databases reject.

PostgreSQL,

> ERROR:  column "t.x" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

SQL Server,

> Column 't.x' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

## Why this bug persists in PostgreSQL

Thanks goes to RhodiumToad on irc.freenode.net/#PostgreSQL for his help trouble shooting this. He also points out the difficulty in resolving this situation

> 20:33 < RhodiumToad> the one problem is that in pg you can do  exists(select func() from ...   where the func() is an SRF that might return 0 rows

An SRF is a [set returning function.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)

In PostgreSQL, we can do for instance use an SRF to generate a series from 1-10 (`generate_series` is in core)

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,10);
```

And, we likewise can put it right here.

```
SELECT generate_series(1,10);
```

Two of them together give us a cross-join (cartesian product)

```
SELECT generate_series(1,10), generate_series(1,2);
```

But, if either of those return 0-rows you get nothing.. Effectually the same as this

```
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x)
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 LIMIT 0 ) AS g;
```

And, that's the problem with optimizing this out entirely. You can have an SRF in a select-list inside of an EXIST statement that returns 0-rows, and forces the EXISTS to evaluate to false.