# ERROR: operator does not exist: text[] ~~ text

Tags: postgresql, array, like, operator, string-searching

We have an easy syntax that allows us to look into an array for a single scalar,

```
SELECT 'foo' = ANY(ARRAY['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
```

We can use the same method to match with `LIKE`

```
SELECT 'foobar' LIKE ANY(ARRAY['foo%', 'bar%', 'baz%'];
```

My question is what if you want to do it the other.

```
SELECT ANY(ARRAY['foobar', 'barbar', 'bazbar']) LIKE 'foo%' 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ANY"
LINE 1: SELECT ANY(ARRAY['foobar', 'barbar', 'bazbar']) LIKE 'foo%';
```

I know that syntax doesn't work, but I have expected this to work.

```
# SELECT ARRAY['foobar', 'barbar', 'bazbar'] LIKE 'foo%';
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text[] ~~ unknown
LINE 1: SELECT ARRAY['foobar', 'barbar', 'bazbar'] LIKE 'foo%';
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I want to filter an array to see if an element exists. Is this possible without using `unnest`?

Comment: Can you use other OPERATOR in the same way?  `SELECT IN ('foo', 'bar')`

Comment: @McNets Yep, `IN ()` is just a minor wrapper around `= ANY( ARRAY[] )`, `SELECT 'foo' IN ('foo', 'bar');` vs `SELECT 'foo' IN ('baz', 'bar');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Postgres manual [suggests](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING) you might have a design issue:

> Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements.

You can make [your operator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194454/1396) more efficient — it's better if it stops checking after the first match:

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION like_in_array( arr text[], pattern text )
> RETURNS bool AS $$
>   SELECT coalesce(( SELECT true
>                     FROM unnest(arr) AS u(n)
>                     WHERE n LIKE pattern 
>                     LIMIT 1),false);
> $$ LANGUAGE sql
> IMMUTABLE;
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1ad1068f69c4ef613943621bc4a94088)*

Comment: Lol, oh yeah, this design is mega s. It's literally from a gigantic Excel sheet and I'm parsing 5 values out from a compound name and some of those values have commas and are arrays. This is by no means a good idea.

Comment: Your answer is probably more useful for most people. =)

Comment: `LIMIT 1 .. COALESCE` is summed up in `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler function for [Evan's operator solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194454/3684), and should be faster, yet:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION like_in_array(_arr text[], _pattern text)
  RETURNS bool LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM unnest($1) n WHERE n ~~ $2)';
```

#### Quick and dirty alternatives

Just cast the array to `text`:

Fulltext matching:

```
SELECT (ARRAY['foobar', 'barbar', 'bazbar'])::text LIKE '%foo%';
```

Pattern and strings just cannot include any of the decorator characters (`,"{}`) to be correct.

Prefix matching:

```
SELECT (ARRAY['foo bar', 'barbar', 'bazbar'])::text ~ '[{",]foo';
```

No decorator characters in the pattern *or* in the strings.
Etc.

This can be indexed, with a trigram index for instance, making it potentially *much* faster than a custom operator.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ba7b35a8437fbceef80da4921866d691)* (based on Jack's fiddle)

Comment: much better/neater!

Comment: any particular reason for `SELECT 1` over `SELECT *`?

Comment: @JackDouglas: No, just (not only) my private convention. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7710153/939860

Comment: Thanks, now I'm tempted to use `SELECT null` or just `SELECT` as per the comments!

Comment: @JackDouglas there is actually a reason to use `SELECT 1` over `SELECT *` in PostgreSQL https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/168052/2639

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the [parray_gin](https://pgxn.org/dist/parray_gin/doc/parray_gin.html) extension ([or more up to date](https://github.com/theirix/parray_gin)).  It creates some new operators for you (although some of them can interfere with built-in operators of the same name if you are not careful) and it also supports indexing.

Answer (score 1):

## Making our own operator

Here is a quick and dirty method of making the operator with [`CREATE OPERATOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html). Not sure if this is the best way. It's 2 AM...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION like_in_array( arr text[], pattern text )
RETURNS bool AS $$
  SELECT n LIKE pattern
  FROM unnest(arr) AS u(n)
  ORDER BY 1 DESC
  LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OPERATOR ~~ (
  LEFTARG   = TEXT[],
  RIGHTARG  = TEXT,
  PROCEDURE = like_in_array
);
```

Test,

```
SELECT ARRAY['foobar', 'barbar', 'bazbar'] LIKE 'foo%';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```